# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms:google-services' not found. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter framework. I am trying to install cloud firestore in flutter but got the problem. Below is my code and gradle files:
Android/build.gradlew:

```
buildscript {
    // ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App/build.gradle is:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.barcode_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'
```

After running flutter run -v or build it in android i got the error:
'ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms:google-services' not found.'

[image]

I tried to almost all the solution available on stackoverflow and github but the problem is still there.

Comment: go to your Android Studio SDK manager and in SDK tools check if Google Play Services and Google Repository are installed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, it would be really useful if you could cite the other solutions you have already tried or explain them. Then you will not receive _repeated_ answers and possible answerers will know what to avoid.

Comment: @Ryosuke yes i have installed these two.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the bottom of your app/build.gradle file you've got:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'
```

This should actually be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Notice the period between `gms` and `google-services`, instead of the colon.

**EDIT:** You're probably having this problem because Google's own docs (last edited 20 March) are incorrect. I've sent them feedback to have this corrected.
[image: Picture of typo in google doc]
 archived here http://archive.is/4Ujuc

Actually Google is correct:  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' is correct and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' is also correct.  One has a COLON and one has a PERIOD.  but the names are so similar that it is easy to think they should be the same.
Just remember "classpath" - COLON, "plugin" - PERIOD.

Comment: didn't help me ... i am having issue of Plugin ```com.google.gms.google-services``` not found ...

Answer (score 0):

If the problem still persists after applying the Jmorris and Johnhunter solution, check this [solution](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3617#issuecomment-699491958)

The solution was:

```
Upgrade the Android Gradle plugin to 3.5.0
Upgrade the Google Services plugin to 4.3.3
Upgrade Gradle to 5.4.1 (the required Gradle version for this Android Gradle plugin version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `google-services.json` file and re configure the firebase with your project.